# Audit is not watching /mnt/foo on RHEL4

Tags: centos, rhel, mount, audit, linux-audit

======New info =====

On my RHEL4 system, auditctl is failing to watch only when something is mounted via the `mount` command. The same directory works fine when it is unmounted. The version of audit is 1.0.16. Whether mounted or not, everything works as intended on CentOS6.7 with audit version 2.4.5. What can be the cause of this?

This is the auditd.conf file on RHEL4.
[image: auditd.conf file on RHEL4]

This is the auditd.conf file on CentOS6.7.
[image: auditd.conf file on CentOS6.7]

Thie is the audit.rules file on both system.
[image: audit.rules file on both systems]

======Old info======

On my RHEL4 system, if I call `auditctl -w /mnt/foo -k mykey` and make modifications to that directory, nothing shows up on my audit.log file other than the fact that a watch has been inserted. There definitely is no typo. If I type `auditctl -l`, I can see the correct thing being watched. Strangely, if I audit watch a directory below that such as `auditctl -w /mnt/foo/testdir -k mykey2`, that works fine. The permission status of `/mnt/foo` is `drwxrwxrwx`, and the permission status of /mnt/foo/testdir is `drwxr-xr-x`.

Even more strangely, on my CentOS6.7 system, doing the same thing, `auditctl -w /mnt/foo -k mykey`, works fine.

Any suggestions why this is happening?